# Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary><string,object>>

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I am getting an error near `return errmsg(ex);`:

> cannot implicitly convert type string to
>   system.collections.generic.dictionary>

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace Webservice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
            //InitializeComponent(); 
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        //public string GetEmployees(string SearchTerm) 
        private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> DatatableToDictionary(DataTable dt)
        {
            var cols = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
            return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                     .ToDictionary(r => dt.Rows.IndexOf(r).ToString(),
                                   r => cols.ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c.ColumnName]));
        }
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> GetEmployees()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NSConstr"].ToString());
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM Contact e WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" + SearchTerm + "%'";
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM Contact e ";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();

                return DatatableToDictionary(ds.Tables[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ***return errmsg(ex);***

            }
        }

        public string errmsg(Exception ex)
        {
            return "[['ERROR','" + ex.Message + "']]";
        }
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't return _both_ a `Dictionary` _and_ a `string` from the same method. Typically, when you have an error, you tend to bubble it up so the higher level code can catch it and do what they like with it. So instead of `return errmsg(ex);` you should just have `throw;` (assuming you're doing other things like logging in your catch. If you're not doing _anything_ in your catch other than `throw;` just get rid of the try/catch block. EDIT: That being said, I'm not sure how this applies to your WebService context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solve my issues:

```
public string GetEmployees()
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NSConstr"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM Contact e ";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
            foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }     

        public string errmsg(Exception ex)
        {
            return "[['ERROR','" + ex.Message + "']]";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a string from method with return type `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>`

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> GetEmployees()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NSConstr"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM Contact e ";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();

        return DatatableToDictionary(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Here you are returning a string, the method signature is Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>
        return errmsg(ex);
    }
}
```

Instead of catching the `Exception` and returning the exception message, let the calling code handle the exception further up the call stack. So you'd have something like:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> GetEmployees()
{                    
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NSConstr"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM Contact e ";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    return DatatableToDictionary(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

Comment: if i remove this ***return errmsg(ex);*** then it throwing error as not all code paths returns a value :( .i dont know how to fix this give me some suggestion pls

Comment: See my edit. Assuming the `DatatableToDictionary()` method returns `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` there is only one code path so you will not receive the error you mention